# How to tell Redis to not consume all available RAM?

Tags: docker, redis

I have an issue with Redis. It consumes all required RAM of my server and eats 100% CPU.

I start Redis via docker-compose on a Debian node:

```
cache:
  mem_reservation: 1G
  networks:
    - be-network
  image: redis:latest
  command: redis-server --save 60 1 --loglevel warning
  volumes:
    - cache:/data
  restart: always
```

My node has 16 GB RAM and 4 vCPUS (Hetzner Cloud). As soon as I start the docker containers, Redis is spawning up eating all the available memory. It also consumes 100% CPU most of the time.

How can I limit its memory consumption using docker(-compose)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to limit it to 3GB, for example, with:

```
command: redis-server --save 60 1 --loglevel warning --maxmemory 3gb
```

---

Or you could do it in your `redis.conf` file with:

```
maxmemory 3gb
```

uncommented in there.

---

You can check the value in use with this command:

```
redis-cli config get maxmemory
```